# How are you supposed to accommodate for diode voltage drops in a circuit?

Tags: circuit-design, diodes

In general, say I wanted to use a schottky diode on my 3.3V bus. Now i'm going to expect something in the ballpark of lets say 0.3V drop across the diode. Is it up to the designer to plan to have a higher voltage previous to the diode to accommodate for the voltage drop if you'd like 3.3V downstream? Or is there something im missing?

Below is an example of how I would use them in a circuit. I need the coin cell to maintain voltage on a single MCU on my 3.3V bus to maintain a bias across an electrochemical sensor. In my case the VBUS is an already regulated 3.3V and VBAT is a 3V coin cell.

[image]

Comment: That depends on what including a diode is intended to accomplish. Why do you want it there?

Comment: I added a schematic of an application to the question.

Comment: Usually such supply diodes feed sections that don't critically depend on a certain voltage to be absolutely solid and stable, e.g. the input to further power regulators/converters.

Comment: What voltage is V bat ?

Comment: VBAT is 3V, VBUS is 3.3V

Comment: Quick comment, if you need "precisely 3.3V" then it is not best practice to try to accommodate the diode drop, which is device and current dependent. It's better to feed a higher voltage and use a regulator after the diode

Comment: I updated your graphic to be more accurate. Please fix it if it no longer properly represents your question. Of course, if something is missing, please add it. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to block any and all VBUS current from leaking into the battery, then yes, you're going to have to accept the voltage drop in the rest of your circuit. If a tiny amount of leakage is acceptable, the Si2323's datasheet says that the body diode's forward voltage drop is typically 0.7 volts. I wouldn't trust that for mass production, but you could measure the leakage to see if it's acceptable for a one-off.

You could also try something like putting an NMOS transistor between the negative terminal of the battery and the circuit ground to block the current from that end.

Answer (score 2):

This is a simple battery switchover circuit with no diode drops.

When the 3.3V supply is present, the gate of Q6 is high and Q6 is turned off. Q8 is on and the gate of Q7 is low and Q7 is on to supply 3.3V to the micro.

When the 3.3V supply is off, the gate of Q6 is pulled low by R6 and Q6 is on to supply battery voltage to the micro. Q8 is off and the gate of Q7 is pulled high by R5, turning off Q7.
[image: Battery switchover circuit]

Comment: Do you think the switch over would be fast enough to no drop power to the MCU?

Comment: Switch-over time depends on the rise & fall time of the 3.3V supply. Normal decoupling caps 1uF//100nF on the micro supply line should stabilize the voltage during switch-over. (or the 10uF in your original schematic)

Comment: In my case I care a lot more about the longevity of the coin cell (VBAT), in terms of how much current is being drawn while its active, currently - no pun intended - my device hibernates and draws about 120µA. Would a circuit like this put more of a load on VBAT?

Comment: When the 3.3V supply is 0V there is no additional current draw from the battery. The battery voltage goes through Q6 to the micro. Q7 & Q8 are off, no path to ground.

Comment: @Dutch2 Are you sure the polarity of Q6 and Q7 isn't reversed?

Comment: @Adam If Q6 & Q7 would be reversed, current would leak into the disconnected source. For example, if Q7 would be reversed, the coin cell voltage would connect through the forward biased diode in Q7 to the 3.3V supply. As the schematic is now, the internal diodes block the connection.

Comment: @Dutch2 Ah, I see now. "Backwards" from the usual orientation (source connected to the highest potential) is indeed correct here. Neat trick!